# Display command result and result number of lines in Bash

Tags: bash, awk

I use a command which display a result in several lines.
I would like to see the result and then display the number of lines of the result.

Today I do :

```
my-command XXX    # to display the result  
echo "Number :" $(my-command XXX | wc -l)    # to display the number of lines
```

But If I want to change the command, I have to change it twice. Is there a better way of acheving the same result?

Comment: Not just change it twice -- you're *running it twice*. There's no guarantee the two runs will have the same output, or that one won't have side effects.

Comment: BTW, there's actually a shell built-in command called `command`, so it's a really bad choice of placeholders. Consider making a habit of using `my-command` or such instead.

Comment: @Charles Duffy you are right thanks. I didn't realize that the second running could be different. Dangerous! Also, thanks for correcting me about "command". I won't do it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use awk instead:

```
awk '1; END{print NR}' <(command XXX)
```

- `1` (default awk action) will print each line of command's output.
- `END{print NR}` will print # of lines in the output of `command` at the end.

Comment: The process substitution isn't necessary here; I'd just write `command XXX | awk '1; END {print NR}'`. Very nice, though.

Comment: Yes process substitution isn't necessary, we can use pipeline as well.

Comment: I wouldn't have found this one by myself! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to be late in marking this answer as right but I had to try it in my work environement first. The other answers are good but I choose this one because it works straight away without adapting with echo or printf.

Answer (score 2):

```
result=$(command)
echo "Number: $(echo "$result" | wc -l)"
```

This puts the output of the command into a variable, which you can then feed into `wc`.

Answer (score 1):

One simple, but memory-intensive, option is to simply store the output in an array.

```
readarray -t result < <(command XXX)
printf '%s\n' "${result[@]}"
printf 'Number: %s\n' "${#result[@]}"
```

You can also use `tee`, although there is probably a race condition here. I wouldn't assume that `Number: NNN` always outputs after the output from `tee`.

```
command XXX | tee > >(printf 'Number: %d\n' $(wc -l))
```

Comment: I didn't think about using an array. Didn't know that I could use "#" this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
output="$(my-command args123)"
echo "$output"
echo "$(echo "$output" | wc -l)"
```

Comment: You are right but so that it can work with my-command, I had to use printf "%s\n" "$output" and not echo. Thanks.